# Prevent byte-compiler warnings after requiring features

Tags: byte-compilation, warning, require

In Elisp packages, we sometimes want to use a feature only if the user has installed another package without specifying that package as a dependency for our own. E.g.

```el
(when (require 'markdown-mode nil 'noerror)
  (markdown-mode))
```

This, however, causes a byte-compiler warning:

> Warning: the function `markdown-mode` is not known to be defined.

What's the right way to address this? `with-no-warnings` is one option, but it needs to be wrapped around every such use. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO, the right way is to ignore it. ;-)

But the standard Emacs answer is to use `declare-function` - see [(elisp) Declaring Functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Declaring-Functions.html).

> All you need to do is add a `declare-function` statement before the
>   first use of the function in question:
>
> ```
>  (declare-function gud-find-c-expr "gud.el" nil)
> ```
>
> This says that `gud-find-c-expr` is defined in `gud.el` (the `.el`
>   can be omitted).  The compiler takes for granted that that file really
>   defines the function, and does not check.
>
> The optional third argument specifies the argument list of
>   `gud-find-c-expr`.  In this case, it takes no arguments (`nil` is
>   different from not specifying a value).  In other cases, this might be
>   something like `(file &optional overwrite)`.  You don’t have to specify
>   the argument list, but if you do the byte compiler can check that the
>   calls match the declaration.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
(require 'markdown-mode nil 'noerror)
...
...
  ...
  (if (fboundp 'markdown-mode)
      ..use markdown-mode..)
```